# Special character output in NSString Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

```
NSString * url;
NSString * device;
NSString * API;
API      = @"http://www.test/";
device   = @"test123";
url      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@update.json?dev=%20%20%20%@", API, device];
```

I want the final url to http://www.test/update.json?dev=%20%20%20%20test123;
However the above I get only http://www.test/update.json?dev=22020test123;  I want those %20 be part of literal string of url. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a `%` sign since it's a special character you need to put `%%` for each `%` within an NSString.

Answer (score 2):

put  \ before  every special  character. That  should work.